# Get the number of posts written by specific user in WordPress page

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

I'm trying to make an author page in my WordPress blog. I have one thing that I try all the way and didn't make it.

I want to display the number of the posts from each author, but I can't make that just use `<?php the_author_posts(); ?>` because I'm not in a single.php file.

So far I know I have to use the `<?php echo get_the_author_posts(); ?>`, but that didn't work either because I can't specify what the author ID is. So I tried something like that: `<?php echo get_the_author_posts( $id_ir_email = '1'); ?>`, didn't work either.

Any idia how to resolve that?

In resume, I just want to write "Admin has written X posts on this blog" outside the single.php

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps or not but I created a blog page where i wanted posts from a specific author:

```
// Reset Query because I had already done a query on the page.
wp_reset_query();

// The Query for a specific author
query_posts('author=4');
```

Info from [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts).

Using this you could loop through and count the posts.

Comment: I think isn't enough because the page will have all the authores.